# Landscape UIView in a UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, landscape

I have a UITabbarController with (so far) two navigation controller items. I can get the application to rotate by adding the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation to each class... but thats not exactly what I want.

What I want to do is to add a button in the UINavigationBar in one of the classes. When this button is pressed I want it to load another view into landscape mode. This view should not show any navigationbar or tabbar controller.

How can I get this to work?

Best regards,
Paul Peelen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use approach similar to Apple's [AlternateViews](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/AlternateViews/index.html) sample.
Basically you should:

1. Create your landscape view with appropriate size (480x300 for landscape if standard statusbar is visible)
2. In your button handler push your landscape calling `-pushModalViewController` on your current view controller
3. Apply necessary affine transformation to your view to be displayed correctly in landscape.

Answer (score 3):

Use `presentModalViewController:animated:` and implement the modal view controller's `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` accordingly.